# Notifications as "others" instead of App itselfs (snap application)

Tags: release-hera, notifications

I run slack as a snap application.
To recognize and adjust slack notifications I changed .desktop properties. According [this link](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/overriding-desktop-files-on-ubuntu-snaps/6599), I added X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true in /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/slack_slack.desktop.

Now, in notifications settings I see the slack application and I can change the bevaviour for slack. But the slack-notifications are still received with "others" instead "slack".

How can I change? Is there a possibility?

--- Installed elementary OS: 5.1.4 Hera